# How to add padding between posts

Tags: posts, wp-query, post-class

Ultimately, I'm really confused on how exactly you create a single class that affects each post in a static home page "recent post" type content area. I want to essentially have it where there's a post with a background, a space, then the next post with the same background, but not have the background behind all the posts. I hope that makes sense. Here's the code I have, but no matter what I do, I'm only able to add a class for one post at a time with the ID.

```
<ul>

<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=5' ); ?>
<div class="new_home_single"><?php the_post()?></div>

<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>


<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>


<?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?>


<?php 
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress already generates class for each posts, you can use these classes using the [**`post_class`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_class/) function.

**Note:** The function can be used either within the loop or by passing the `$post_id`

So you would have

```
<ul>
    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=5' ); ?>

    <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>

        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'post' ); ?>>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

            <?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?>
        </div>

    <?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: OMG Thank you sooo much!! Seriously! What's crazy is that I did this before. Guess why it didn't work? I had to empty browser cache. Which is weird because it's nothing but an underscores framework. No clue how to turn that off.

Answer (score 0):

> I hope that makes sense.

Partly :) But if I've understood it right and you want to style each post excerpt you'll need a container around it that you can reference with CSS, and currently, you've got your class "new_home_single" outside the while loop, so that single class is being applied to all your post excerpts.

So the simplest change to your code is to add a wrapper around the excerpt like this:

```
<div class="post-excerpt">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?>
</div>
```

And then some CSS to style each excerpt, using margin instead of padding to have background-free space between each one:

```
.post-excerpt {
     background-color: #dddddd;
     margin: 2rem 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It was somewhat what I asked. I know it was confusing, but this actually comes in handy later. Thank you.