# How do I get row padding in a post feed?

Tags: loop, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a custom post loop going into a template I made - the row has to be outside of the loop, or the posts don't line up vertically. However, I need some spacing between the posts - image below to illustrate:
[image: Showing my row of posts with no padding]

I have tried setting the row padding/margin in css but obvs it only applies to the row containing the loop and not anything flowing into the loop. I am not sure how I go about styling this. I am assuming I add another class around the col which I have also tried.

Comment: Oops, [I found the answer to this here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/250637/how-to-add-padding-between-posts/250640).

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible ways that you could do, these are:

1. Adding `<br />` html tag
2. Making it inside `<div style="...">....</div>`

**Example:**

```
<div style="padding:10px;">...</div>
```

You can also use `<table>` if you want

Answer (score 0):

Hi Tracy you can also use Bootstrap classes for better designing:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h3>Column 1</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
          <p>Ut enim ad..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h3>Column 2</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
          <p>Ut enim ad..</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h3>Column 3</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor..</p>
          <p>Ut enim ad..</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```